# Simple model theory question

Tags: logic, predicate-logic, model-theory

Let $L$ be a first-order language, and let $F[v]$ be an $L$-formula with one free variable. Suppose that $\mathfrak{M}$ is an $L$-structure such that $\mathfrak{M} \vDash F$, that is $\{x \in M,$ satisfying $F[v] \}$ is non empty.

Now, we know that $\vdash F[v] \Leftrightarrow \forall v F[v]$, but there is no reason for the above set to be all of $M$.

Thus, we have $\mathfrak{M} \vDash F[v]$ and $\mathfrak{M} \nvDash \forall v F[v]$ even though $\vdash F[v] \Rightarrow \forall v F[v]$. 
This means that a model $\mathfrak{M}$ can satisfy a formula $F[v]$ without satisfying its syntactical consequences (as in, being a model is not stable by syntactic consequences). Isn't it weird? Why are we defining the deduction rules of the syntax like that?

Answer (score 3):

Careful.

(1) You need to distinguish

$$\vdash F[v] \rightarrow \forall v F[v]$$

from

$$\vdash F[v]  \Rightarrow\ \vdash\forall v F[v]$$

The first fails in standard FOL systems (e.g. Mendelson's)

(2) It is also unhappy to write $\mathfrak{M} \vDash F[v]$; it is $\mathfrak{M}$-plus-an-assignment that satisfies the open wff.

Comment: Are you using $\rightarrow$ for the symbol in $L$ and $\Rightarrow$ for the intuitive "implies" ? (That is, in this case, the deduction rule)

Comment: The other way round. I'm using the single arrow $\to$ for the object-language conditional (i.e. the conditional in the formal language), and the double arrow $\Rightarrow$ for the informal meta-linguistic 'implies'.

Comment: So: we must distinguish "it is provable that $A \to B$" and "if it is provable that $A$ then it is provable that $B$". In the presence of wffs with free variables, treated one conventional way, the expected relation between these two fails.

Comment: Yes but then if we have ($\vdash F[v]$ implies $\vdash \forall v F[v]$), we have the following formal proof: 1. $F[v]$, 2. $\forall v F[v]$ (generalization rule), 3. $\forall v F[v] \rightarrow (F[v] \rightarrow \forall v F[v])$ (tautology), 4. $F[v] \rightarrow \forall v F[v]$ (modus ponens), shouldn't we?

Comment: No. You have simpoly misapplied the Generalization rule. Check the restrictions on the use of the rule in your favoured textbook. (Or note that if you are using a system like Mendelson's with unrestricted Generalization, it can only be applied to a theorem, not to an assumption like $F[v]$.)

Comment: I don't get it. That's how we use modus ponens too right? We know $A$ and $A \rightarrow B$, allowing us to conclude $B$. Here, I know $F[v]$, so by generalization rule I can conclude $\forall v F[v]$. What is the mistake?

edit: the textbook I'm using is using an unrestricted generalization rule apparently. So I guess my problem is that I have no right to claim $1. F[v]$ because there is a free variable?

Comment: Sorry: I'm calling a halt. Check your textbook for explanation about why Generalization is subject to restrictions.

Comment: @AlexKruckman: I guess that's where my problem is. Does that mean that the only way to prove a formula with a free variable is through logic axioms involving the universal quantifier and not the existential one? (Say, like $\forall v F[v] \rightarrow F_{v/v} = F[v]$)

Comment: Sorry, I deleted my comment, so we're out of order. I'm reposting it: @sure In your proof, where do you get $F[v]$ to start with?

Comment: @sure That depends on the details of your proof system.

Comment: My proof system is as follow: the deduction rules are given by the modus ponens and the (apparently unrestricted) generalization rules. The logic axioms are given by the tautologies (defined as the tautologies of the propositional calculus where you replace the atomic formula of prop. calc. by first-order logic formula), and the following three axioms: a) $\exists v F \leftrightarrow \neg \forall v \neg F$, b) $\forall v (F \rightarrow G) \rightarrow (F \rightarrow \forall v G)$ with $v$ not a free variable in $F$, c) $\forall v F \rightarrow F_{t/v}$ for $t$ a term and the usual restrictions.

Comment: [That's basically Mendelson's axiomatic system. So you can't start a proof with Fv. The only entries in proofs are instances of axioms and what are derived from them.]